# Query not adding in rows

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm creating table in a database using this query

```
CREATE TABLE `Quote 1` (
ID INT(6) PRIMARY KEY,
`Task Title` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`Install Cost` INT NOT NULL,
`Schedule Position` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
`Method` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`Task Time` INT NOT NULL,
`Van Parts` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`Order Parts` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`Parts Cost` INT NOT NULL,
`Equiptment` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`Description` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL,
`Group` VARCHAR(90) NOT NULL
)
```

Then I'm trying to insert rows into the table using this

```
INSERT INTO `Quote 1`(`ID`, `Task Title`, `Install Cost`, `Schedule Position`, `Method`, `Task Time`, `Van Parts`, `Order Parts`, `Parts Cost`, `Equiptment`, `Description`, `Group`) VALUES (1,`TESTA`,2,`TESTB`,`TESTC`,3,`TESTD`,`TESTE`,4,`TESTF`,`TESTG`,`TESTH`)
```

Why this row is not being added? Pretty sure I've check all of the data types but I'm new to MySQLi and can't find the problem.

Comment: Do you get any error Messages?

Comment: Why do you have spaces for your table name and your fields? This will make your project harder to make it more dynamic. I suggest you do not have any white spaces for your table name or your fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `` in column values and use single quote `' '`;

```
INSERT INTO 
`Quote 1`
(
`ID`, `Task Title`, `Install Cost`, 
`Schedule Position`, `Method`, `Task Time`, 
`Van Parts`, `Order Parts`, `Parts Cost`, 
`Equiptment`, `Description`, `Group`
)
VALUES 
(
  1,'TESTA',2,
  'TESTB','TESTC',3,
  'TESTD','TESTE',4,
  'TESTF','TESTG','TESTH'
)
```